pegar columna y filas de Excel a un formulario en Vue
Buenos días estoy realizando un modulo , en la cual deseo pegar datos de Excel y organizado en una lista en vue
en la cual usando la propiedad  split("\t") puedo separa la información por columna y me hace falta separa por filas en la cual le muestro el código
la consola me imprime la siguiente información y no encuentro la forma de separa por filas

["manzana verde ","33","450 manzana roja","44","480 limon grande","55","660"]

si desea ve el codigo completo por codepen https://codepen.io/Marcos-Alberto-Saavedra-Sanabria/pen/bGXweoW
Código VUE JavaScript
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    
    
    lista: [
      { id: 0, nombre: "Manzana", cantidad: 3, valor: 4500 },
      { id: 0, nombre: "pera", cantidad: 5, valor: 5600 },
      { id: 0, nombre: "Limon", cantidad: 2, valor: 2500 }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    pegarExcelColumnaFilas(indexCampo) {
      var columnas = this.lista[indexCampo].nombre.split("\t");
      var filas = this.lista[indexCampo].nombre.split(" ");
      console.info(filas);
      console.info(columnas);
      for (let indexColumna = 0;indexColumna < columnas.length;indexColumna++) {
        if (this.lista[indexCampo] != null) {
          this.lista[indexCampo].nombre = columnas[0];
          this.lista[indexCampo].cantidad = columnas[1];
          this.lista[indexCampo].valor = columnas[2];
        } else {
          this.lista.push({
            id: 0,
            nombre: columnas[0],
            cantidad: columnas[1],
            valor: columnas[2]
          });
        }
        //}
      }
    }
  }
});

Templete del código
<body>
  <section class="hero is-fullheight is-dark is-bold">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="columns is-vcentered has-text-centered">
          <div id="app" class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Nombre </th>
                <th>Cantidad </th>
                <th> Valor </th>
              </tr>
              <tr v-for="(data,index) in lista">
                <td>
                  <input @change="pegarExcelColumnaFilas(index)" v-model="lista[index].nombre">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input v-model="lista[index].cantidad">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input v-model="lista[index].valor">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

</body>


Lo que mostras de ejemplo no parece tener que ver con tu codigo.. porque haces un split de un objeto que no es una cadena donde valga la pena hacer un split??
